# ¿Puedo guardar permanentemente el contenido de un ArrayList de un Bean en Spring-Hibernate?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, hibernate, richfaces

¡Hola! Estoy teniendo problemas con algo que pienso que es muy trivial, pero no estoy seguro de qué puede estar fallando.

Tengo una clase de Java Bean, llamémosla EjemploBean, donde tengo un atributo de tipo List (llamémoslo listaValores) al que se le añaden valores dependiendo de en qué columnas clique en una tabla de mi vista JSF, llamémosla vista.xhtml. Las columnas tienen un tag de richfaces a4j:support para interaccionar con la clase EjemploBean mediante Ajax, por lo que he creado un método en EjemploBean que será el que sea llamado al hacer clic. Al hacer clic por primera vez, el método guarda los valores en el atributo listaValores sin problema y los cambios pueden verse reflejados en la vista si añadimos cualquier elemento donde representar el atributo listaValores. Sin embargo, si vuelvo a hacer clic en otra columna, la listaValores es inicializada de nuevo como vacía en lugar de añadir más valores a la lista y acumular los valores de los dos clics realizados.

Mi pregunta es: ¿acaso los atributos se reinician al llamar un método del Bean más de una vez o qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Un saludo y gracias por vuestras respuestas.

EDITO: Voy a dejar el código por aquí para que os resulte más sencillo poder comprenderlo (tanto vista XHTML como clase Java Bean).

EDITO2: Resuelto. Tal y como me han indicado en los comentarios, @Scope("request") está inicializando el bean siempre que se envía una petición. Cambiándolo por "session" ya hace que funcione correctamente.

```
    <ui:composition template="/templates/main.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">TITLE</ui:define>

        <ui:define name="body">


           <table id="tablaFicheros" width="100%">
               <thead>
                    <th class="ficheros" >
                        <h:outputText  value="Categoría" />
                    </th>
                    <th class="ficheros" >
                        <h:outputText value="Subcategoría" />
                    </th>
                    <th class="ficheros" >
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
                    </th>
               </thead>

               <tbody id="cuerpoTabla">
                       <c:forEach items="#{informesFicherosBean.listCategorias}" var="categoria" varStatus="status">
                            <tr id="filaCategoria#{categoria.idCategoria}">             
                                <td class="ficheros">

                                    <h:form>
                                        <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="listaSubCategorias" actionListener="#{ informesFicherosBean.abrirSubCategorias}">
                                            <f:attribute name="idCategoria" value="#{categoria.idCategoria}" /> 
                                        </a4j:support>
                                        <h:outputText value="${categoria.txtNombre}"/>
                                    </h:form>
                                </td>   
                            </tr>
                       </c:forEach>
               </tbody>

           </table>

             <rich:dataList value="#{informesFicherosBean.subcategoriasAbiertas}" id="listaSubCategorias" var="item" >
                <h:outputText value="#{item.txtNombre}" id="fichero#{item.id}" />
            </rich:dataList>
        </div>  

        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Java class:

```
    @Service("informesFicherosBean")
@Scope("request")
public class InformesFicherosBean {

    /**
     * Log
     */
    protected static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(InformesFicherosBean.class);


    private List<InfInformesFicheros> listFicheros = new ArrayList<InfInformesFicheros>();


    private List<InfCategoria> listCategorias = new ArrayList<InfCategoria>();

    private List<InfCategoria> subcategoriasAbiertas;


    /**
     * Servicio
     */
    @Autowired
    private IInfInformesFicherosModelSvc infInformesFicherosModelSvc;

    /**
     * Servicio
     */
    @Autowired
    private IInfCategoriaModelSvc infCategoriaModelSvc;


    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
    }

    public List<InfInformesFicheros> getListFicheros() {
        if(listFicheros.isEmpty())
            return infInformesFicherosModelSvc.loadAll(); //Return all elements from this db table

        return listFicheros;
    }

    public void setListFicheros(List<InfInformesFicheros> listFicheros) {
        this.listFicheros = listFicheros;
    }

    public List<InfCategoria> getListCategorias() { //return all objects from categories db table

        if(listCategorias.isEmpty()){
            List<InfCategoria> categoriasActuales = infCategoriaModelSvc.listCategorias();
            setListCategorias(categoriasActuales);
        }

        return listCategorias;
    }

    public void setListCategorias(List<InfCategoria> listCategorias) {
        this.listCategorias = listCategorias;
    }

    public List<InfCategoria> getSubcategoriasAbiertas(){
        if (this.subcategoriasAbiertas==null){
            setSubcategoriasAbiertas(new ArrayList<InfCategoria>());
        }

        return this.subcategoriasAbiertas;
    }

    public void setSubcategoriasAbiertas(List<InfCategoria> subcategoriasAbiertas){
        this.subcategoriasAbiertas = subcategoriasAbiertas;
    }

    public void abrirSubCategorias(ActionEvent event){

//debugging here it always return getSubcategoriasAbiertas as an empty list

        Long idCategoriaParam = (Long) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("idCategoria");
        Integer idCategoria = idCategoriaParam.intValue();

        infCategoriaModelSvc.abrirSubCategorias(getSubcategoriasAbiertas(), getListCategorias().get(idCategoria - 1)); //add elements to attribute List "subcategoriasAbiertas"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes anotada la clase con `@Scope("request")`, eso significa que se creará una instancia nueva para cada request. Por tanto siempre estarás trabajando con un objeto recién inicializado. Si quieres mantener en el lado servidor la información, quizá deberías probar con otro scope (¿`"session"`, quizá?). Aunque si tus requerimientos incluyen que tu aplicación sea *stateless* (como son las API REST, por ejemplo), entonces tendrías que mandar y enviar esa lista del cliente al servidor en cada request.

Comment: Efectivamente, cambiando el Scope por "session" ya funciona correctamente como buscaba. Era una parte de código que copié de otro trabajo y nunca supe cómo funcionaba la etiqueta Scope. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha salvado :D

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido te recomiendo marcarla como aceptada, así la pregunta aparecerá como "respondida" y te llevarás un par de puntos de reputación ;)

Comment: No había visto esa opción, ¡hecho!